# Is it possible to get element, that triggered window unload in IE (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onbeforeunload

I am trying to handle beforeunload event. The idea is to show "You are attempting to navigate away, the unsaved data will be lost..." message only in case browser window/tab is being closed and in case some certain controls on page are clicked. So far I determined if the message needs to be displayed by CSS class of a control that is clicked. The code :

```
 function RaiseSubmitPrompt(event, confirmText) {
    var eTarget =  event.target.activeElement;
    if (eTarget.className.indexOf('noNavigationPrompt') < 0) {
        if (HasPendingComments()) {
            return confirmText;
        }
    }
}
```

This works for FF and Chrome, but crashes on IE. I do know, that there is no "activeElement" property in case of IE, but the most serious problem seems to be, that in EI event.target always points to window object, and it seems, that the attempt to somehow get reference to clicked button or link is hopeless by definition. Is it true, or are there any ways to get that reference in beforeunload event handler code ?

Comment: If you want to track buttons and links, attach onmousedown event on them and store last-clicked-element... Than in onbeforeunload you can use it.

Comment: sorry, did not read your comment properly, before answering first time. you have a very good point, I will try it

Comment: Let say a button is bound to some JS, that posts back in some cases, and does not - in others. If the button is clicked, but the latter JS does not fire postback, the button is still stored in let say a variable. If later on user decides to close browser window, onbeforeunload handler will fetch that previously stored button and think, that it caused unloading, which is not true. Seems, that it will not work

Comment: You should bind before other script does same. That's why I also suggested onmousedown instead of click (which happens later).

Comment: Seems interesting, but probably I was too tired to understand. I picked the other way to solve the problem : unbinding 'beforeunload' and binding it again as follows                  `function EscapePrompt() {
    $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
    setInterval(function () { BindBeforeUnload() }, 1000);
}`